# No VMA signal from laptop

Tags: debian, display, thinkpad

My trusty everyday computer is an IBM Lenovo X60 Thinkpad, running Debian. A few weeks ago I managed to break the screen by compressing it between the collapsed seats of my girlfriend's car. I ordered a replacement, but I needed to get some files off it, and used the SD reader.

I hooked up an external monitor and USB mouse and got to work. 3 days later, I had to return the monitor to its owner, so I went out and bought another one at a thrift store. It worked fine for about an hour, then I started to get weird, laggy pixelation in a diagonal pattern (Imagine an X drawn on the screen, with one quadrant taking seconds or minutes longer to load than the others; alternating).

I rebooted the computer manually (i.e. pressing the power button until it died and then pressing it again to turn it on. After this, the monitor did not display any signal from the laptop. In fact, it announced as much, and that it was going into sleep mode.

I thought the VMA cable might be to blame, so I replaced it. No dice. Borrowed another monitor, hooked it up, same deal. I should also note that when this setup was actually working, the laptop screen (broken and 100% unreadable, but still capable of displaying pixels) would go dark as soon as the external VMA was hooked up. Now it stays light, so I have to assume that the problem originates with the computer somehow.

How can I diagnose it without any sort of working screen? Is this a hardware problem?

Comment: Please format your question to multiple passages instead of a big passage. It makes it easy for the user to read and increases your chances of getting an answer